# Controlling WIndows 7 "Sync Center" with GPO's

Tags: windows-7, synchronization, folder-redirection

We are looking at bringing Windows 7 into the workplace, we have a new W7 laptop we are testing. Our work environment heavily relies on folder redirection. In the XP environment we have a GPO for users that forces folder syncs at logon and logoff, this does not seem to be supported in the GPO's of our server 03 machines for windows 7 sync center. Is there a way to have a GPO to control the sync time of W7 sync center, such as on 2008 server?

Answer (score 2):

Just remember to administer GPOs from the same level OS level as the clients you're targeting. If you don't have a Win2008R2 server, just install the admin tools onto your Win7 and you'll have access to everything you need.

Be sure to check out GPO on technet, http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/windowsserver/grouppolicy/default.aspx, there are some guides on managing Win7 systems in environments with lower-level server OSes.

Answer (score 1):

As already mentioned you need to use the Remote Server Administration Tools on Windows 7 to administer the GPO.

Get this: http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=7D2F6AD7-656B-4313-A005-4E344E43997D&displaylang=en

When you install that, go to "Programs and Features" and "Turn Windows features on or off" and turn on "Remote Server Administration Tools". Then if you fire up mcc., you will be able to add the "Group Policy Management" snap-in.

If you check the GPO Reference guide here: http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?displaylang=en&FamilyID=18c90c80-8b0a-4906-a4f5-ff24cc2030fb

Then you should be able to find the right entry to modify.